# what is recommended to store project configuration details in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm a beginner with spring boot and java. My question is what is recommended to store Environment configuration details such as bigquery database name, aws service unqiue ids which are used in my project.

So, It is better to store in a class which is in core project or it is better to store in application.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Because spring boot is so lightweight, a lot of projects use Spring boot for microservices. and in a microservice world, it's best and almost needed to store your configs in a centralized and secure place, so you can change any of them when you want.it's hard to save them in Java classes but you can easily save them with .yml or properties. in almost all cases .yml files will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some options to save the information of the configurations in an application. One of them is use a  *.yml to save all the information because you can have different configurations each of them per environment